# Is there a way to create a command line wrapper for a bash file?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

The title says it all. I would like to type "run" in the command line and it would execute /pathtoscript/script.sh.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file named `run` with the contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /pathtoscript/script.sh "$@"
```

Place the file in your path and set the executable bit.

#### What is "your path"?

At the command line, type:

```
echo $PATH
```

You will see a colon-separated list of directories.  These are the directories that the shell searches when looking for a command to run.  They are collectively called the path.  You will want to place your new file `run` in any one of those directories.

#### Alternate approach for interactive work

If you just want `run` to work when you are working interactively, you can create an alias:

```
alias run=/pathtoscript/script.sh
```

If you want this alias saved permanently, put that line in the `.bashrc` in your home directory.

Comment: @Autospamfighter Both are permanent.  There are times when aliases don't work, so using the `run` file is more robust.

Answer (score 2):

In *nix shells, the way this is done is by adding an **executable file** (or symbolic link to an executable file) to one of the **directories** listed in **the `PATH` variable**. From a hypothetical session:

```
$ which foo
which: no foo in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin)
$ foo
bash: foo: command not found
$ echo "$PATH"
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
$ sudo ln -s /path/to/my/script /usr/local/bin/foo
$ foo
[whatever your script prints]
```

Comment: "\*nix" is just a historical shorthand for "[Unix-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like)". It's not something you have to install.